# Visual Level Filter Equal To Column Value

Tags: powerbi

I have a measure in my date table that calculates the week number of the year for last week. LastWeekNum = WEEKNUM(TODAY(), 1) -1

I want to apply this to a visual, so logically: WeekOfYear = LastWeekNum.

Is there some way to set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible to do with some DAX and model editing, but I'd first try using **Relative date filtering** in the visual level filter settings to see if you can do it the easy way.

[image: Relative Date Filtering]

---

If that doesn't work, I'd suggest creating a Boolean column on your date table and using that column to filter your visual instead. Visual level filter, Basic filtering, `IsLastWeekNum is 1`

```
IsLastWeekNum = IF(WEEKNUM(DateTable[Date]) = [LastWeekNum], 1, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but unfortunately thats not what I need in my case.

The end result I'm building will have sales totals for 2016,2017,2018 for a specific week of the year, so I cannot use relative date filtering.